# BIDS 2008 SSIS Package Data Flow Task fails validation and returns "VS_ISBROKEN" Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids, sql-agent-job

A BIDS 2008 SSIS package that I am working is failing validation when it reaches any Data Flow Task in the package. I am able to run the SSIS package within BIDS 2008 on my computer locally. When I run the SSIS package through an SQL Agent Job, the package fails with the error message below. I have researched error code 0x80004005 and error code 0xC004706B through Google searches, but have not found anything that is of use.

The SSIS package in question is one of several SSIS packages that run together in the same SQL Agent Job. The other SSIS packages in the original SQL Agent Job all are able to run successfully. This leads me to believe that the SQL Agent Service Account and Proxy Account are configured with the appropriate permissions. A DBA was able to confirm that the Service Account and Proxy Account do have the appropriate permissions.

The SQL Agent Job runs the SSIS package using the Operating System (CmdExec) type and the SSIS package has Run64BitRuntime set to FALSE so the SSIS Package is running under the 32-bit runtime.

For debugging purposes, I recreated the Data Flow Task, Database Connections, and related source and destination tasks in a new SSIS Package from the original SSIS package. The debugging SSIS package is able to run locally on my computer, but fails when I try to run using a new SQL Agent Job setup exactly like the original SQL Agent Job.

I have also use different Database Connections such as Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 10.0, 10.1, 11.1, and Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. All of which have failed when I test the debugging SSIS package

I have verified that the metadata for the OLE DB Source and Destinations match the datatypes and lengths in the SQL Server Database tables. I have verified that the stored procedure used by the OLE DB Source task in the Data Flow Task work when ran on SQL Server Management Studio and the Service Account has permissions to run the stored procedure.

I think that is every bit of information that I can recall from working on troubleshooting this issue.

Has anyone else come across this error before? Any possible solutions to attempt?

Any help is welcomed!

Error Message:

> Executed as user: domain\SQLAgentServiceAccount. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  1:37:09 PM
>
> Error: 2014-08-14 13:37:09.94     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Data Flow Task - OLEDB Source [1]
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred.
>
> Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Syntax error or access violation".
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2014-08-14 13:37:09.94     Code: 0xC004706B     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: "component "OLEDB Source" (1)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2014-08-14 13:37:09.94     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: One or more component failed validation.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2014-08-14 13:37:09.94     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow task
>   Description: There were errors during task validation.
>   End Error
>
> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>
> Started:  1:37:09 PM  Finished: 1:37:09 PM  Elapsed:  0.219 seconds.  Process Exit Code 1.
>
> The step failed.

Comment: When you migrate a package from one machine to another and have a validation error, it is most likely caused by the configuration of your connection manager or differences in the database that it is actually connecting to.  You would get a login failed message if it was a problem with your service account.  However, you have "Syntax error or access violation."  Is the command in the OLEDB source an expression in a variable?  Is this SSIS 2008r2 or under or ssis 2012 and up?  Are you using package configs or params to set you connection string?

Comment: The command in the OLEDB source is an embedded stored procedure that takes in two parameters and returns a dataset to move to a table in another database. The SSIS package was developed in BIDS 2008 and being ran through a SQL Job on SQL Server 2008 R2. Using a config file to get the SQL Server name.

Comment: When you test this locally, are you connecting to the same server as when you run it through SQL agent?  If not, is the proc the same in both places?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to the same server that I am run the package through SQL agent.

Comment: Are the two parameters set the same way in both cases?  Also, you mentioned 64 bit vs 32, is this important for what you are connecting to?  You are executing under 64 bit according to the error message that you posted.

Comment: Yes, the two parameters are connecting the same way in both cases. Once I locally run the package and it is successful, I move it to the correct file directory on the server to run it from the SQL Agent Job.

As for executing under 64 bit, I have set the Run64BitRuntime to both True and False, yet still the same error message. Since this package does not use any Microsoft Jet Providers, then it can run as either 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: Can you ask the DBA to login as the service account and execute the proc to ensure that this user has appropriate permissions on those objects? If you actually have dev tools installed on the server, it may be worth opening the package there to see what object is specifically broken and if everything is being set the way that you expect it to.  Lastly, can you run this on a 3rd machine to see if you can replicate the behavior?

Comment: Found the problem. The service account did not have the execute permissions on the stored procedure. Granted the service account execute permission and re-ran the SSIS package through SQL Agent and completed successfully. Appreciate the help @MarkWojciechowicz for being a sounding board and troubleshooting!

Answer (score 1):

I found the this solution :

Ensure that the connection string in Connection Manager has `"Provider=SQLNCLI11.1; Persist Security Info=True; Auto Translate=False;"`

I did it and it worked for me on Hyperscale / SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of strange error that I got a while ago and I used the following to resolve the problem:

Run command prompt as Administrator
Type the following command and hit Enter:     **regsvr32 jscript.dll**
Type the following command and hit Enter:     **regsvr32 vbscript.dll**

Comment: I assume the .dll files are registered since other SSIS packages on the server are able to run successfully. I won't be able to know this due to the fact that my own user account does not have permissions to log into the server or make any changes to system files. Although, unregistering and then re-registering the .dll files could potentially be a solution. I would have to run it by the DBAs to see if that is a feasible task to do.

Comment: IF that is the case how about creating a batch file and call it via SQL Agent. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was that the service account that is running the SQL Agent job did not have execute permissions on the stored procedure being executed through the Data Flow Task. Gave the service account execute permissions and the SSIS package was able to successfully execute.